# what's different LaunchScreen.storyboard and Main.storyboard in iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode

I created a application in Xcode 7.2 ,This is Main.storyboard .

I did't modify the LaunchScreen.storyboard. I build it ,but failed

Comment: LaunchScreen.storyboard is for the splash screen :)

Answer (score 2):

LaunchScreen.storyboard file is used for the splash screen - it is shown full-screen while the app is launching and loading the root view controller

Main.storyboard - is the main interface file with (all) the view controllers of your app